# Циклы перемещения по коллекциям

Tags: java

Есть 2 типа цикла для перемещения по коллекции:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){ iterator.next().... }
```

и

```
for(SomeObject o : SomeCollection){o ....}
```

В чем их разница?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница в том, что втором случае ошибка - нет такой конструкции (по крайней мере до 6 java включительно). Там скорее всего должно быть так

```
for(SomeObject o : SomeCollection){o ....}
```

В большинстве случаев разницы почти никакой. Оптимизатор сам умеет все хорошо оптимизировать и код будет практично идентичный. Например, если в качестве коллекции выступает обычный массив, то код будет заменен на обычный цикл [for с индексом](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html).

Различия появляются, когда в дело вступает многопоточность и итерируемый объект нужно защищать мютексами. В этом случае лучше использовать первый тип.

Говорят, что второй тип будет оптимальным в будущем, когда компилятор научиться хорошо оптимизировать код и сможет делать итерации цикла в нескольких потоках. Но, возможно, это фантастика.

Comment: Дополнение. Если надо будет удалять из коллекции, во втором варианте получим исключение `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` (даже в случае одного потока). Удалять можно только через `iterator.remove()`. [тык](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html#Iterator)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov добавлять тогда тоже нельзя, получим исключение

Comment: @voipp, разумеется, только удаление в цикле foreach - частый юзкейс, т.е. фильтрация (filter, reduce...), а вот добавление в таком цикле даже не знаю когда бывает.

Comment: Небольшое дополнение, на самом деле, оба варианта индентичны для jvm - foreach цикл является лишь синтаксическим сахарком.